# java.nio.file.Path cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, eclipse, okhttp

I have added package 'squareup.okhttp' and got above error. Really don't know what it mean.

following is the code and the error giving by eclipse in problems tab.

```
@Override 
public Source source(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    return Okio.source(file);
}


java.nio.file.OpenOption cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files FileSystem.java /myapp/src/com/squareup/okhttp/internal/io
```

I am using JDK 1.6. Added source code of okhttp2.5.0.jar in my code instead of jar.

Please help me to sort out this.

Comment: are you using a JDK <= 1.6?

Comment: `java.nio.file.OpenOption` was added in JDK 1.7 and is used by `okhttp2.5.0.jar`. In order to use that jar you need to upgrade to Java 1.7 or better 1.8.

Comment: **you need to use JDK7** to use those classes. I'm not sure if Okhttp still falls back to Java6 methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am using JDK 1.6

The `java.nio.file` package was only introduced in Java 7.